# ¿Cómo imprimir 10 registros por cada tema desde la misma consulta MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente consulta, donde actualmente se imprime registros por una categoría o tema especifico por ejemplo:

```
$section_category = 'news'; //noticias
```

Actualmente tengo más de dos temas o categorías `news, sports, technology` la misma que se encuentra en la columna `main_cover` de la misma tabla `news_sport`

Está es mi consulta:

```
    $ACTIVE = 1;
    $LANGUAGE = 'es';
    $limit_data = 10;

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT n.id_news_sport as id,
                                n.url as url,
                                n.cover_page as cover_page,
                                n.mini_title as mini_title,
                                n.mini_description as mini_description,
                                n.date_post as date_post,
                                n.main_cover as main_cover,
                                u.trade_brand as trade_brand
                            FROM news_sport n
                            LEFT JOIN users u ON n.id_author=u.id_user
                            WHERE n.language=? AND n.main_cover=? AND n.active=? ORDER BY n.id_news_sport DESC LIMIT ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssii",$LANGUAGE,$section_category,$ACTIVE,$limit_data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $json = array();
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $json['id'],
        $json['url'],
        $json['cover_page'],
        $json['mini_title'],
        $json['mini_description'],
        $json['date_post'],
        $json['main_cover'],
        $json['trade_brand']
    );
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
```

He tratado de obtener 30 registros desde la misma consulta, es decir 10 registros de `news` 10 de `sports` y 10 registros de `technology` agregue un `GROUP BY n.main_cover` por lo que he consultado pero no obtengo lo que espero.

Por el momento estoy teniendo estos resultados en `JSON` https://jsfiddle.net/k8xv6o9j/

Y, lo que deseo lograr es lo siguiente, si se observa en `main_cover` de los resultados `JSON` esta `news, sports, technology` lo que quiero es imprimir esos resultados pero 10 registros de cada uno, por ejemplo:

```
"articles":[
{
    "id": 1009,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1009/final-de-ida-de-ligapro-entre-independiente-del-valle-y-emelec-se-posterga-por-fuerte-lluvia",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/7jCfeo3.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Final de ida de LigaPro entre Independiente del Valle y Emelec se posterga por fuerte lluvia",
    "mini_description": "El partido fue reprogramado para las 20:00 de este domingo.",
    "date_post": "2021-12-06 00:15:07",
    "main_cover": "news",
    "trade_brand": null
},
    "id": 1009,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1009/final-de-ida-de-ligapro-entre-independiente-del-valle-y-emelec-se-posterga-por-fuerte-lluvia",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/7jCfeo3.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Final de ida de LigaPro entre Independiente del Valle y Emelec se posterga por fuerte lluvia",
    "mini_description": "El partido fue reprogramado para las 20:00 de este domingo.",
    "date_post": "2021-12-06 00:15:07",
    "main_cover": "news",
    "trade_brand": null
},
    "id": 1009,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1009/final-de-ida-de-ligapro-entre-independiente-del-valle-y-emelec-se-posterga-por-fuerte-lluvia",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/7jCfeo3.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Final de ida de LigaPro entre Independiente del Valle y Emelec se posterga por fuerte lluvia",
    "mini_description": "El partido fue reprogramado para las 20:00 de este domingo.",
    "date_post": "2021-12-06 00:15:07",
    "main_cover": "news",
    "trade_brand": null
},
    "id": 1009,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1009/final-de-ida-de-ligapro-entre-independiente-del-valle-y-emelec-se-posterga-por-fuerte-lluvia",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/7jCfeo3.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Final de ida de LigaPro entre Independiente del Valle y Emelec se posterga por fuerte lluvia",
    "mini_description": "El partido fue reprogramado para las 20:00 de este domingo.",
    "date_post": "2021-12-06 00:15:07",
    "main_cover": "news",
    "trade_brand": null
},
    "id": 1009,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1009/final-de-ida-de-ligapro-entre-independiente-del-valle-y-emelec-se-posterga-por-fuerte-lluvia",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/7jCfeo3.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Final de ida de LigaPro entre Independiente del Valle y Emelec se posterga por fuerte lluvia",
    "mini_description": "El partido fue reprogramado para las 20:00 de este domingo.",
    "date_post": "2021-12-06 00:15:07",
    "main_cover": "news",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1008,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1008/manta-se-aferra-a-la-serie-a-tras-golear-3-tantos-a-0-al-olmedo-de-riobamba-ya-descendido-a-la-serie-b-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/mUj5k5w.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Manta se aferra a la Serie A tras golear 3 tantos a 0 al Olmedo de Riobamba, ya descendido a la Serie B 2022.",
    "mini_description": "El equipo manabita fue muy fuerte de local y sac\u00f3 3 puntos claves para escapar del descenso y se prende la pelea por la permanencia.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 02:21:36",
    "main_cover": "sports",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1008,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1008/manta-se-aferra-a-la-serie-a-tras-golear-3-tantos-a-0-al-olmedo-de-riobamba-ya-descendido-a-la-serie-b-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/mUj5k5w.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Manta se aferra a la Serie A tras golear 3 tantos a 0 al Olmedo de Riobamba, ya descendido a la Serie B 2022.",
    "mini_description": "El equipo manabita fue muy fuerte de local y sac\u00f3 3 puntos claves para escapar del descenso y se prende la pelea por la permanencia.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 02:21:36",
    "main_cover": "sports",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1008,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1008/manta-se-aferra-a-la-serie-a-tras-golear-3-tantos-a-0-al-olmedo-de-riobamba-ya-descendido-a-la-serie-b-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/mUj5k5w.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Manta se aferra a la Serie A tras golear 3 tantos a 0 al Olmedo de Riobamba, ya descendido a la Serie B 2022.",
    "mini_description": "El equipo manabita fue muy fuerte de local y sac\u00f3 3 puntos claves para escapar del descenso y se prende la pelea por la permanencia.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 02:21:36",
    "main_cover": "sports",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1008,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1008/manta-se-aferra-a-la-serie-a-tras-golear-3-tantos-a-0-al-olmedo-de-riobamba-ya-descendido-a-la-serie-b-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/mUj5k5w.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Manta se aferra a la Serie A tras golear 3 tantos a 0 al Olmedo de Riobamba, ya descendido a la Serie B 2022.",
    "mini_description": "El equipo manabita fue muy fuerte de local y sac\u00f3 3 puntos claves para escapar del descenso y se prende la pelea por la permanencia.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 02:21:36",
    "main_cover": "sports",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1008,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1008/manta-se-aferra-a-la-serie-a-tras-golear-3-tantos-a-0-al-olmedo-de-riobamba-ya-descendido-a-la-serie-b-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/mUj5k5w.jpg",
    "mini_title": "Manta se aferra a la Serie A tras golear 3 tantos a 0 al Olmedo de Riobamba, ya descendido a la Serie B 2022.",
    "mini_description": "El equipo manabita fue muy fuerte de local y sac\u00f3 3 puntos claves para escapar del descenso y se prende la pelea por la permanencia.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 02:21:36",
    "main_cover": "sports",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1007,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1007/ldu-de-quito-empato-con-orense-y-no-ira-a-la-libertadores-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/I2geFn5.jpg",
    "mini_title": "LDU de Quito empat\u00f3 con Orense y no ir\u00e1 a la Libertadores 2022",
    "mini_description": "El mal rendimiento del equipo albo lo deja fuera de Libertadores tendr\u00e1n que conformarse con disputar la Copa Sudamericana 2022.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 01:17:35",
    "main_cover": "technology",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1007,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1007/ldu-de-quito-empato-con-orense-y-no-ira-a-la-libertadores-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/I2geFn5.jpg",
    "mini_title": "LDU de Quito empat\u00f3 con Orense y no ir\u00e1 a la Libertadores 2022",
    "mini_description": "El mal rendimiento del equipo albo lo deja fuera de Libertadores tendr\u00e1n que conformarse con disputar la Copa Sudamericana 2022.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 01:17:35",
    "main_cover": "technology",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1007,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1007/ldu-de-quito-empato-con-orense-y-no-ira-a-la-libertadores-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/I2geFn5.jpg",
    "mini_title": "LDU de Quito empat\u00f3 con Orense y no ir\u00e1 a la Libertadores 2022",
    "mini_description": "El mal rendimiento del equipo albo lo deja fuera de Libertadores tendr\u00e1n que conformarse con disputar la Copa Sudamericana 2022.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 01:17:35",
    "main_cover": "technology",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1007,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1007/ldu-de-quito-empato-con-orense-y-no-ira-a-la-libertadores-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/I2geFn5.jpg",
    "mini_title": "LDU de Quito empat\u00f3 con Orense y no ir\u00e1 a la Libertadores 2022",
    "mini_description": "El mal rendimiento del equipo albo lo deja fuera de Libertadores tendr\u00e1n que conformarse con disputar la Copa Sudamericana 2022.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 01:17:35",
    "main_cover": "technology",
    "trade_brand": null
},
{
    "id": 1007,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/1007/ldu-de-quito-empato-con-orense-y-no-ira-a-la-libertadores-2022",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/I2geFn5.jpg",
    "mini_title": "LDU de Quito empat\u00f3 con Orense y no ir\u00e1 a la Libertadores 2022",
    "mini_description": "El mal rendimiento del equipo albo lo deja fuera de Libertadores tendr\u00e1n que conformarse con disputar la Copa Sudamericana 2022.",
    "date_post": "2021-11-22 01:17:35",
    "main_cover": "technology",
    "trade_brand": null
},
]
```

> Nota: He repetido los registros `JSON` 5 de cada uno, para no hacerlo extenso y que se pueda apreciar los resultados que deseo poder imprimir, no importa sino están en orden siempre cuando sean 10 de cada tema o categoría de: `news, spors, technology`

¿Cómo puedo obtener los resultados deseados?

---

Según algunos ejemplos que me han expuesto he practicado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT n.id_news_sport as id,
       n.url as url,
       n.cover_page as cover_page,
       n.mini_title as mini_title,
       n.mini_description as mini_description,
       n.date_post as date_post,
       n.main_cover as main_cover,
       u.trade_brand as trade_brand
FROM news_sport AS n
LEFT JOIN users u ON n.id_author=u.id_user
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT n1.main_cover
   FROM news_sport n1
   LIMIT 10
   ) AS ou 
WHERE n.active = '1' GROUP BY n.main_cover DESC LIMIT 10
```

Aun no se como funciona pero sigo sin obtener los resultados deseados, solo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existen otros ejemplos, pero no es compatible con la versión 5 de `MYSQL`

Comment: Da mas detalles de tus tablas, y como quieres que te salga el resultado, abajo o al lado_

Comment: @Japv Hola ya estoy imprimiendo los resultados deseados en JSON como se puede observar https://jsfiddle.net/k8xv6o9j/ pero lo único que quiero es que en esos registros me muestren 10 registros por cada tema que se encuentra en la columna `main_cover` por ejemplo ahora en mis resultados esta datos al azar, pero yo quiero 10 productos de `sports` 10 de `news` y así entre las otros temas, recordado que la columna `main_cover`  es que tiene dichos temas dicha columna esta en la misma tabla de las noticias `news_sport`

Comment: @Japv No hay mas detalles que aclarar de las tablas amigo, solo quiero una condición en la consulta que me muestre 10 registros de manera `DESC` de catada tema de la columna `main_cover` nada más

Comment: Si tienes q aclarar, primero pq no dices la estructura de tus tablas, segundo porque no pones un ejemplo de como quieres q se visualicen tus datos, es decir una columna para las noticias y otra para las deportivas o ambas en la misma columna, revisa bien

Comment: @Japv He editado mi pregunta y con ejemplos y nuevos intentos espero este mas claro.

Comment: Llamando la consulta preparada 3 veces lo consigues ¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea general es:

1. Agrupar por categoría
2. Aplicando un ordenamiento
3. Limitando el ordenamiento

Asumiendo que quieres mostrar los 10 más recientes por categoría:

a) Con la opción equivalente a `row_num()`:

```
SELECT id
     , main_cover
  FROM ( SELECT @idGrupo := if( @ultimoGrupo = main_cover
                                or @ultimoGrupo := main_cover
                              , @idGrupo+1
                              , 1
                              ) gid
              , ns.*
             FROM news_sport ns
               JOIN ( SELECT @idGrupo:=0, @ultimoGrupo:=null ) vars
           WHERE main_cover in ('news','sports','tech')
           ORDER BY main_cover, id DESC
       ) t
  WHERE gid <= 10;
```

La agrupación se hace ordenando primero por la categoría y controlando con la variable de usuario `@ultimoGrupo` el cambio de categoría. El ordenamiento se hace a nivel sub-consulta. El límite se establece en la consulta principal.

b) Con `find_in_set()`:

```
  SELECT ns.*
    FROM news_sport ns
      INNER JOIN ( SELECT main_cover
                        , group_concat(id ORDER BY id DESC) ids
                     FROM news_sport
                     WHERE main_cover in ('news','sports','tech')
                     GROUP BY main_cover
                 ) g
        ON    ns.main_cover = g.main_cover
          AND find_in_set(ns.id, g.ids) <= 10
    ORDER BY main_cover, id DESC
```

La agrupación se hace con `GROUP BY` y el ordenamiento se hace en el `group_concat()`. El límite se establece en las condiciones del JOIN.

c) Llamar la sentencia preparada por cada categoría:

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare( "SELECT n.*
                                 , u.trade_brand
                              FROM news_sport n
                                LEFT JOIN users u 
                                  ON n.id_author=u.id_user
                              WHERE n.language=? 
                                AND n.main_cover=? 
                                AND n.active=? 
                              ORDER BY n.id_news_sport DESC LIMIT ?
                           "
                         );
    $json = array();
    foreach( array('news', 'sports', 'technology') as $section_category ){
        $stmt->bind_param('ssii',$LANGUAGE,$section_category,$ACTIVE,$limit_data);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
            $json[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Tanto la agrupación como el ordenamiento y la limitante es por cada `execute()` de la sentencia preparada.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo con un UNION de dos SELECT , uno para cada main_cover, pero eso te dejaría sin que fuera dinámico.

La otra podrías hacer una subconsulta donde les generes campo contador dependiendo de su main_cover, lo puedes hacer con ROW_NUMBER() y ya con eso seleccionar los que su numero de columna sea menor a 10, mas o menos asi:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT
     T.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.main_cover ORDER BY T.main_cover) number
  FROM news_sport T
  LEFT JOIN users U ON T.id_author=U.id_user
) as R
WHERE R.number <= 10
```

y ya seria cuestión de que completaras con los campos seleccionados y el WHERE dentro de la subconsulta, creo.

Veo que pusiste algunos datos para poder probar, eh calado la query y exceptuando el hecho de que no tengo la relacion con usuarios para hacer el ELFT join, me trae este resultado, tomando en cuenta solo 3 por el numero de registros que das

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando para versiones anteriores  a la 8 de MySQL encontre este tutorial para emular el ROW_NUMBER() : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ Siguiendolo defini la QUERY de la siguiente manera:

```
set @row_number := 0;

SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT
     T.*,
     @row_number:= CASE WHEN @ordered_by = T.main_cover THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END as number,
         @ordered_by := T.main_cover as ordered_by
  FROM news_sport T
) as R
WHERE R.number <= 3
```

Poniendo que solo traiga solo como prueba. y me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala esta te sirva.

Comment: Hola no entendí se ve como complejo

Comment: Pues de forma resumida, el select dentro del from lo que hace es consultar a news_sport y asignarle un numero de columna por cada registro, que es lo que hace ROW_NUMBER() con la condicion de que ese row number sea con base a main_cover, es como si lo agrupara por main_cover , ya con ese numero asignado, solamente selecciona todos los que ese numero sea menor a 10, es decir, le traeria 10 de cada categoria.

Comment: lo he ejecutado directamente al SQL de MYSQL pero arroja error y cada columna y tabla son correctos pero pese a ello muestra errror

Comment: Hola, acabo de notar que agregaste algunos datos como ejemplos, me tome la libertad de tomarlos para poder hacer una prueba, lo triste es que a mi si me funciona, actualice la respuesta con una imagen con mi resultado. Pero eso no sirve de mucho. Seria bueno si pudieras compartir el error para ver mas o menos por donde va el asunto y ve si pudiera ayudar un poco.

Comment: Te adjunto una captura amigo del error que me sale: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnhO4.jpg

Comment: creo que tu version de MySQL no soporta ROW_NUMBER() esta se soporta desde la version 8

Comment: tengo un hosting compartido ya intenté actualizar pero no sé puede, está en la versión 5. Alguna otra alternativa ?

Comment: Hola @Fernando buscando por google segui este enlace https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ que explica como emular el row_number, agrege en la respuesta codigo actualizado, a ver si te sirve, o mejor dicho, ojala, de ahi en mas ya no sabria.

Answer (score 1):

eso que comentas se puede hacer con Cross Apply.

Si no he entendido mal, en la tabla news_sport tienes todas las noticias y quieres mostrar 10 registros de cada categoria cruzando contra la misma tabla y columna  main_cover.

Lo primero que te recomendaria es que separases las categorias en una tabla individual, pero usando tu modelo actual, puedo obtener el listado de categorías unicas mediante group by de la tabla news_sport por la columna main_cover y luego el cruce contra las noticias de cada una de esas categorias mediante un cross apply:

```
SELECT 
n.id,
n.url,
n.cover_page,
n.mini_title,
n.mini_description,
n.date_post,
n.main_cover,
n.trade_brand
FROM 
    (select main_cover from news_sport group by main_cover) categories 
    Cross Apply (
        select 
            n1.id_news_sport as id,
            n1.url as url,
            n1.cover_page as cover_page,
            n1.mini_title as mini_title,
            n1.mini_description as mini_description,
            n1.date_post as date_post,
            n1.main_cover as main_cover,
            u.trade_brand as trade_brand,
            n1.active,
            n1.language
        from news_sport n1
            LEFT JOIN users u ON n1.id_author=u.id_user
        where
            n1.main_cover = categories.main_cover
        limit 10
    ) n
WHERE n.language=? AND n.main_cover=? AND n.active=? ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT ?
```

Si la query anterior funciona, para cada caregoría mostrará hasta un máximo de 10 notificias. No tengo un mysql instalado y no he podido probar la query, pero al menos en SQL Server estoy casi seguro que funciona.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, se ve bien solo tengo una duda, en el `SELECT 
n.id,
n.url,` debe ir así o se deben corregir por ejemplo `u.trade_brand` en vez de `n.trade_brand`

Comment: No me funciona, así que limpie un poco de columnas y quite el JOIN pero sigue igual https://ideone.com/OEyemp no funciona

Comment: Según lo investigado no hay `CROSS APPLY` en `MYSQL` se usa `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tienes una versión antigua de MySQL, te puede servir esta consulta.

La idea es agrupar las noticias por autores en una sub-consulta, y luego usar `FIND_IN_SET()` para el límite entre `N` y `M` ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585351/5587982)).

Aquí te dejo un Fiddle (por cierto se agradece si nos ahorras el trabajo inicial, creando un fiddle con un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable parecido a este, sólo con las tablas columnas esenciales):

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id_user INT
);
INSERT INTO users (id_user) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO users (id_user) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO users (id_user) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO users (id_user) VALUES (4);

CREATE TABLE news_sport (
  id_news_sport INT,
  mini_title VARCHAR(50),
  id_author INT
);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (1,'News 1',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (2,'News 2',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (3,'News 3',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (4,'News 4',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (5,'News 5',1);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (6,'News 6',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (7,'News 7',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (8,'News 8',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (9,'News 9',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (10,'News 10',1);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (11,'News 11',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (12,'News 12',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (13,'News 13',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (14,'News 14',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (15,'News 15',1);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (16,'News 16',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (17,'News 17',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (18,'News 18',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (19,'News 19',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (20,'News 20',1);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (21,'News 21',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (22,'News 22',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (23,'News 23',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (24,'News 24',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (25,'News 25',1);

INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (26,'News 26',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (27,'News 27',3);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (28,'News 28',1);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (29,'News 29',2);
INSERT INTO news_sport (id_news_sport,mini_title,id_author) VALUES (30,'News 30',1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
  id_user,
  id_news_sport,
  mini_title
FROM
  news_sport 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id_author,
      id_user,
      GROUP_CONCAT(id_news_sport ORDER BY id_news_sport ASC) group_author
    FROM
      news_sport INNER JOIN users u ON u.id_user=news_sport.id_author
    GROUP BY id_author) group_news
  ON news_sport.id_author = group_news.id_author
     AND FIND_IN_SET(id_news_sport, group_author) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GROUP BY 
    id_news_sport, 
    id_user, 
    mini_title   
ORDER BY
    news_sport.id_author ASC,
    news_sport.id_news_sport ASC;
```

| id_user | id_news_sport | mini_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | News 1 |
| 1 | 3 | News 3 |
| 1 | 5 | News 5 |
| 1 | 6 | News 6 |
| 1 | 8 | News 8 |
| 1 | 10 | News 10 |
| 1 | 11 | News 11 |
| 1 | 13 | News 13 |
| 1 | 15 | News 15 |
| 1 | 16 | News 16 |
| 2 | 4 | News 4 |
| 2 | 9 | News 9 |
| 2 | 14 | News 14 |
| 2 | 19 | News 19 |
| 2 | 24 | News 24 |
| 2 | 29 | News 29 |
| 3 | 2 | News 2 |
| 3 | 7 | News 7 |
| 3 | 12 | News 12 |
| 3 | 17 | News 17 |
| 3 | 22 | News 22 |
| 3 | 27 | News 27 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iEW6AKatngRZUGpdXqHV8a/0)

Comment: Hola, en su ejemplo no veo `main_cover` que son las categorías o los temas de la noticias que desean obtener 10 de cada tema, dónde los resultados deseados son como las capturas que ha mencionado `@StialManstike` pero que lastimosamente no funcionó su primer ejemplo verificaré mañana lo otro puesto.

Comment: @Fernando yo puse un **Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable** para demostrar el funcionamiento. Si observas, he creado una tabla `news_sport` solamente con tres columnas para simplificar. En tu contexto real sólo tienes que agregar las columnas que necesites tanto en el `SELECT` como en la parte del `GROUP BY`.